# How to get manifest from string representation for type with parameters

Tags: scala, reflection

There is a way for get class by name, for example `Class.forName("com.project.model.User")`.

Is it possible to get manifest from string representation? For example, there are two situations:

Get manifest from type-name without type parameters - it works:

```
val str = "com.project.model.User"
val mf = Manifest.classType(Class.forName(str))
```

How to get manifest from type-name with type parameters:

```
val str = "com.project.model.Event[User]"

val mf: Manifest[Event[User]] = howToGetManifestByName(str)  // ???
```

environment: scala-2.11.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ManifestFactory.classType(cls)` to get the manifest for a class instance.

```
import scala.reflect.ManifestFactory

class MyClass(str: String)
val c = Class.forName("MyClass")
val manifest = ManifestFactory.classType(c)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works. But how about getting manifests for types with parameters? For example `com.project.event[com.project.model.User]`

Comment: @JohnMullins You can't, it only contains class information.